# How to use AMD GPU for fastai/pytorch?

Tags: pytorch, gpu, fast-ai, amd-gpu

I'm using a laptop which has Intel Corporation HD Graphics 5500 (rev 09), and AMD Radeon R5 M255 graphics card.

Does anyone know how to it set up for Deep Learning, specifically fast.ai/PyTorch?

Answer (score 37):

### Update 3:

Since [late 2020](https://github.com/llvm/torch-mlir/releases/tag/snapshot-20211006.3), [torch-mlir](https://github.com/llvm/torch-mlir/) project has come a long way and now supports all major Operating systems. Using torch-mlir you can now use your AMD, NVIDIA or Intel GPUs with the latest version of Pytorch.
You can download the binaries for your OS from [here](https://github.com/llvm/torch-mlir/releases).

### Update 2:

Since October 21, 2021, You can use [DirectML](https://github.com/microsoft/directml#pytorch-with-directml) version of Pytorch.
DirectML is a high-performance, hardware-accelerated DirectX 12
based library that provides GPU acceleration for ML based tasks. It supports all DirectX 12-capable GPUs from vendors such as AMD, Intel, NVIDIA, and Qualcomm.

**Update**:
For latest version of `PyTorch with DirectML` see: [torch-directml](https://pypi.org/project/torch-directml/)
you can install the latest version using pip:

```
pip install torch-directml
```

For detailed explanation on how to setup everything see [Enable PyTorch with DirectML on Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/ai/directml/gpu-pytorch-windows).

side note concerning pytorch-directml:
Microsoft has changed the way it released `pytorch-directml`. it deprecated the old 1.8 version and now the offers the new `torch-directml`(as apposed to the previously called `pytorch-directml`).
It is now installed as a plugin for the actual version of Pytorch and works align side it.

**Old version:**
The initial release of pytorch-directml (Oct 21, 2021):

> Microsoft has release [Pytorch_DML](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectML/issues/52#issuecomment-948948611) a few hours ago.
> You can now install it (in windows or WSL) using [pypi package](https://pypi.org/project/pytorch-directml/):
> **pytorch-directml** 1.8.0a0.dev211021
> `pip install pytorch-directml`

So if you are on windows or using WSL, you can hop in and give this a try!

### Update :

As of Pytorch 1.8 (March 04, 2021), AMD ROCm versions are made available from Pytorch's official [website](https://pytorch.org/). You can now easily install them on Linux <strike>and Mac</strike>, the same way you used to install the CUDA/CPU versions.

Currently, the pip packages are being provided only. Also, the Mac and Windows platforms are still not supported (I haven't tested with WSL2 though!)

### Old answer:

You need to install the ROCm version. The official AMD instructions on building Pytorch is [here](https://rocmdocs.amd.com/en/latest/Deep_learning/Deep-learning.html#pytorch).

There was previously a wheel package for rocm, but it seems AMD doesn't distribute that anymore, and instead, you need to build PyTorch from the source as the guide which I linked to explains.

However, you may consult this page, to build the latest PyTorch version: [The unofficial page of ROCm/PyTorch](https://github.com/aieater/rocm_pytorch_informations).

Comment: Is there any support the Vega 11? I only see the Vega 10 in that list.

Comment: I dont know, there seem to be an issue at their repo, might be worth having a look[link](https://github.com/RadeonOpenCompute/ROCm/issues/949)

Comment: @hossein, could you explain me or help me to use "torch-mlir" in Windows for convert a Cuda project to DirectMl for use AMD card. I am trying use my AMD in some AI projects but i cant, I've seen this alternative, but i am not sure how use it. Try it but only CPU is used. What should i do?

Comment: @Milor123 comments section is not a good place for these questions, please either ask a separate question detailing what you've exactly done and what's wrong, or kindly refer to the official torchmlir discord or it's GitHub repositorys issues.

Comment: @Milor123 also note that torchmlir and directml are two completely separate projects. Also it doesn't convert your cuda codes to some other codebase so to speak, please refer to the documentations for further clarifications and then ask a new question if the problem still persists.

Answer (score 6):

Update: In March 2021, Pytorch added support for AMD GPUs, you can just install it and configure it like every other CUDA based GPU. [Here](https://pytorch.org/blog/pytorch-for-amd-rocm-platform-now-available-as-python-package/) is the link

Don't know about PyTorch but, Even though Keras is now integrated with TF, you can use Keras on an AMD GPU using a library PlaidML [link](https://plaidml.github.io/plaidml/docs/install#installation-instructions)! made by Intel. It's pretty cool and easy to set up plus it's pretty handy to switch the Keras backends for different projects

Comment: Note that pytorch for amd is not available on windows as of this comment